# Jekyll: Using Front Matter in Includes

Tags: if-statement, jekyll, liquid

Is it possible to use front matter in an include. I've got an include called `image.html` that looks like this.

**image.html**

```
{% if layout == 'page' %}
  <img src="{{ site.url }}/public/img/{{ include.url }}" class="page">
{% else %}
  <img src="{{ site.url }}/public/img/{{ include.url }}">
{% endif %}
```

And an `about.md` file that looks like this:

**about.md**

```
---
layout: page
---

{% include image.html url="img.jpg" %}
```

But for some reason, it isn't recognising the `if layout` statement. Any idea how to get this to work?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Full issue below:

If the `image.html` include is included on a page, the include needs to have a completely different layout, with two encapsulating elements (`container` and `sm-col-12`). Hope the below makes a bit more sense than my original question.

**image.html**

```
{% if include.size == 'full' and include.type != 'gif' %}
<section class="image full-width">
  <img src="{{ site.url }}/public/img/{{ include.name }}.{{ include.type }}">
</section>
{% elsif layout == 'page' and include.type != 'gif' %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="sm-col-12">
    <section class="image">
      <img src="{{ site.url }}/public/img/{{ include.name }}.{{ include.type }}">
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
{% elsif include.type != 'gif' %}
...
{% else %}
...
{% endif %}
```

**about.md**

```
---
layout: page
---

{% include image.html name="zifferblatt" type="jpg" %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an include file, you still have the `page` variable available.

In your case, you to call `page.layout` :

```
<img src="{{ site.url }}/public/img/{{ include.url }}" {% if page.layout == 'page' %}class="page"{% endif %}>
```

Comment: Sorry. The example I've posted was a stripped down version of the problem I'm facing. I'm not actually able to use the ` page` variable in the `.md` file and instead I **need** it in the include file. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: Can you give the full context. Are you in a loop, listing post or pages ?

Comment: Posted an update alongside the original question. I hope that provides a bit more context...

Comment: same answer `{% elsif page.layout == 'page'...` because from inside `image.html`, you're still in the `about.md` page context. So you can still reach the about page layout from `page.layout` variable.

Comment: Ahhhhh! I was missing the `page` in `page.layout`. Thanks for this, and sorry for the oversight.